# Show tooltips onHover for all the charts at same date

Tags: angular, tooltip, echarts

I'm working with echarts and angular 12 and i'm lookin on how to trigger tooltips on other charts when hovering on one chart. I saw that there is dispatchAction method in echarts but I didn't found how to use it to trigger tooltips on other charts.

Can some one help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which type of chart you use.
I try it use bar chart.
Is this you need to result?

```js
var option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name:'Testname',
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};

var option2 = {
tooltip:{
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer:{
        show:false
        }
        },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name:'Testname2',
      data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
      type: 'bar',
      smooth: true
    }
  ]
};
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
var myChart2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main2'));
myChart.setOption(option);
myChart2.setOption(option2);

myChart.on('mouseover',function (params){
    var event=params.event;
    myChart2.dispatchAction({
                type: 'showTip',
                x:event.offsetX,
                y:event.offsetY,
            });
    });
    myChart.on('globalout',function(params){
      myChart2.dispatchAction({
        type: 'hideTip'
      });
    });
```

```css
#main{
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  float:left;
}
#main2{
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="Zh-TW">
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
   <div id="main" ></div>
   <div id="main2"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```